# Finding where a value has changed over time in solr

Tags: solr

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out if there's a way to find all records where a particular data point has changed over time using solr, but I can't seem to find anything on the web, and I can't figure it out.

I'm using solr 5.4.1.

I have a field: `gp`, saved as a numerical field in my schema, so I can run statistics on it and what not.  What I'd like to see ultimately is a list of all `pn` fields where the `gp` in that `pn` field has either increased or decreased over time, where time is held in a separate `o_date` field as a `YYYY-MM-DD` variable.

I've done a lot with `solr.stats` and `solr.facets`, but I'm not sure this is doable in solr....

The only way I can consider doing this now is by creating smaller queries that I export into another language, performing this logic on a line by line basis in a huge for loop - but I feel that's vastly inferior to letting solr do it if it can.

Comment: Do you have many documents with the same value for `pn` and are interested in seeing where the value has changed for later documents (same `pn`, larger `o_date`), or do you have one document for `pn` and just the last date when the field changed?

Comment: I have several documents with the same `pn` - anywhere from 2 to 1,000, with `o_date`s that spread out over years, (same `pn`, larger or smaller `o_date`)